# CLIPSJNI.SymbolValue cannot be cast to CLIPSJNI.MultifieldValue

Tags: logic, rules, clips

I'm trying to run the example [CLIPS](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/) GUI projects, both versions 0.2 and 0.3, however without success. Nothing special - I create a simple Eclipse project with the codes, using Debian 64bit and I always end up with the "CLIPSJNI.SymbolValue cannot be cast to CLIPSJNI.MultifieldValue" exception. I got the libCLIPSJNI.so in `/usr/lib64`. Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: You might want to include information about where you downloaded the libraries as the original CLIPSJNI package from SourceForge does not include libraries for Debian 64bit.

Comment: From http://sourceforge.net/projects/bunks/files/0.5/

Comment: BTW, I got the same exception on Win7 64bit, however I don't remember from where I downloaded the 64bit .dll file.

Comment: Are you having issues running the bunk files (which are not part of the CLIPSJNI) or the CLIPSJNI examples files (animal, auto, sudoku, wine). I didn't have any issues running the example files with Win7 64bit.

Comment: I can't run the examples from Win7 64bit command line - "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CLIPSJNI/Environment" exception occurs.

Comment: I have compiled libCLIPSJNI.so for the 0.3 version of CLIPS on Java 1.7.0_11 and 1.6.0_45. I'm still getting the "CLIPSJNI.SymbolValue cannot be cast to CLIPSJNI.MultifieldValue" exception, when I try to run the codes in Eclipse.

Comment: I can't reproduce any of the behavior you're seeing in Win7 in a 64bit environment. I downloaded the CLIPSJNI code from sourceforge.net/projects/bunks/files/0.5 and downloaded a 64-bit dll from http://wise.vub.ac.be/~lhoste/public/CLIPSJNI-64.zip. I can't reproduce the "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: CLIPSJNI/Environment" exception you've described.

Comment: Can you reproduce the exception in the title of this question? I am doing something wrong, but after several hours of configuring and coding and stuff I can't see what it is... I even installed a virtual machine with WinXP on it. I just started an Eclipse project on Java 1.6, with the AnimalDemo codes, the .dll and .jar from CLIPS 0.2 and still got the darn exception :/

Comment: I am not able to reproduce any of the behavior you've described. On Win7 all I had to do was unzip the CLIPSJNI source, replace the DLL with a 64 bit version, and then all of the examples ran without issues using the commands listed in the CLIPSJNI documentation.

Comment: You mean you ran the examples from command line? I need to create a Eclipse project, that's the main issue of this question. Have you tried to create one? If yes, using what version on Eclipse & CLIPS?

Comment: What's the point of trying to create an Eclipse project if you've got the wrong DLL? If you can't get it to work from the command line, it's unlikely you're going to get it to work from Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, latest update. I'm able to run the CLIPS 0.3 examples from command line, Win7 64bit, Java 1.7 using the .dll file from the link in your comment above. In Eclipse Juno I get "java.lang.Exception: PrimitiveValue FALSE is not multifield type." when trying to run the AnimalDemo, AutoDemo, WineDemo. And a "[EXPRNPSR3] Missing function declaration for row." when I try to solve the SudokuDemo (it does start).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that either the rule or resource files are not being found in your projects. There are probably multiple (or better) ways to do this, but what I did was create a CLIPSJNI project to contain the CLIPSJNI.dll, CLIPSJNI.jar, and libCLIPSJNI.jnilib files and then a separate project for each of the demos. I placed the clp files at the root level of the demo project, the java code within the src directory and the resources folder within the src directory:

```
Animal
   src
      AnimalDemo.java
      resources
         AnimalResources.properties
            .
            .
            .
   animaldemo.clp
   bcdemo.clp
```

I placed an archive zip of the projects at https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/Misc/: CLIPSJNI_0_3_Eclipse_projects_64Bit.zip

Comment: it doesn't work .. primitiveValue doesn't have any method named .size() or .get() and so on ... why have you changed it?

Comment: Some of the methods that applied only to multifields were moved out of the primitiveValue class in CLIPSJNI 0.5. The example eclipse project uses the example source code from the 0.3 release so if you're using some source from the 0.5 release you need to replace the other code as well.